# Passing a static instance as a variable? (Noesis Javascript)

Tags: c#, javascript.net

I'm trying to use Javascript.NET, but I'm having trouble adding a reference to static classes.

```
jc.SetParameter("test", Log);
```

Also, "Log" is a static class.

I get the 'is a type but is used as a variable' error.

Comment: SetParameter expects a variable but you are passing a class

Comment: How do I reference it then?

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to do but you need to pass intance of class and you have static class

Comment: So, how? I cant pass the static instance in there?

Comment: try `new Log()` you can call static methods from object anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static classes cannot be instantiated.  You can't pass them as a parameter to methods.